# Restrict unauthenticated users to first page results

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

What's the best way to restrict anonymous users to only first page of search results ?

Off the top of my head, I can think of two approaches:

1. Permit all requests to the resource and modify `Pageable` on the fly if unauthenticated.
2. Use antMatchers(Spring securuty) to enforce authentication for paginated requests.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with spring security approach using regexMatcher.

```
.regexMatcher("/api/myresource\\?page=0\\&size=20.*").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
```